# Incomplete jQuery Carousel (Magento Shop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, carousel

Someone has built a carousel for our [webshop](https://www.prestaq.nl/prestaq_nld/prestaq-patchkast-b600-d800-27he-glazen-voordeur.html#gallery), but it is not functioning correctly. When you click one of the arrow buttons, the images will move to the left or right. But as you might have noticed already, the images just disappear into the void.

Obviously it should move to the first image when the last one has been reached and someone clicks on "next", and to the last image when the first one has been reached.

Note: the reason he used "jQuery" instead of "$" is because "$" is in conflict with Magento.

This is the code that is used:

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div id="moveleft">&lt;</div>
    <ul class="gallery-content">
      <li>
         <a href="http://test.prestaq.nu/media/catalog/product/cache/27/image/fae68339a485a19e15750344af4b35e2/4/2/42he_glas_1_24.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">
         <img src="http://test.prestaq.nu/media/catalog/product/cache/27/image/300x/fae68339a485a19e15750344af4b35e2/4/2/42he_glas_1_24.jpg" alt="">
       </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="http://test.prestaq.nu/media/catalog/product/cache/27/image/fae68339a485a19e15750344af4b35e2/4/2/42he_glas_2_9.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">
          <img src="http://test.prestaq.nu/media/catalog/product/cache/27/image/300x/fae68339a485a19e15750344af4b35e2/4/2/42he_glas_2_9.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://test.prestaq.nu/media/catalog/product/cache/27/image/fae68339a485a19e15750344af4b35e2/4/2/42he_glas_3_1_2.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">
          <img src="http://test.prestaq.nu/media/catalog/product/cache/27/image/300x/fae68339a485a19e15750344af4b35e2/4/2/42he_glas_3_1_2.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://test.prestaq.nu/media/catalog/product/cache/27/image/fae68339a485a19e15750344af4b35e2/4/2/42he_glas_4_15.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">
          <img src="http://test.prestaq.nu/media/catalog/product/cache/27/image/300x/fae68339a485a19e15750344af4b35e2/4/2/42he_glas_4_15.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://test.prestaq.nu/media/catalog/product/cache/27/image/fae68339a485a19e15750344af4b35e2/4/2/42he_glas_5_15.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">
          <img src="http://test.prestaq.nu/media/catalog/product/cache/27/image/300x/fae68339a485a19e15750344af4b35e2/4/2/42he_glas_5_15.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      </ul>
    <div id="moveright">&gt;</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 ul, li { list-style: none; }
.gallery {
    min-height: 340px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.gallery ul.gallery-content {
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 55px;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top: -300px;
}
.gallery img {
    float:left;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.gallery #moveleft {
    height: 300px;
    width: 50px;
    line-height: 300px;
    border: #CCC solid 1px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-size:45px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}
.gallery #moveright {
    height: 300px;
    width: 50px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size:45px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -300px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    border: #CCC solid 1px;
}
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.gallery #moveleft').click(function() {
        jQuery('.gallery li').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "-=300px" //moves left
        });
    });
    jQuery('.gallery #moveright').click(function() {
        jQuery('.gallery li').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "+=300px" //moves right
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using OwlCarousel for simple jQuery Carousel on Magento. This jQuery plugin also support touch slide (work very well on mobile), which is a plus if your Magento website is responsive.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. But I was actually hoping for an addition in code to 'finish' this rule.